# Is the $l_p$-direct sum of uncountably many separable Banach spaces is separable?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1\leq p<\infty$, let $\Lambda$ be an uncountable index set, and let $(E_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ be a family of (infinite dimensional) separable Banach spaces. In general, it is known that the $l_p$-direct sum of the Banach spaces $E_\alpha$, denoted by $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}E_\alpha\right)_{l_p}$, is a Banach space under the norm defined by

$\hspace{3cm}\displaystyle \parallel x\parallel_p:=\left(\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\parallel x_\alpha\parallel^p\right)^{1/p}$, $\hspace{1cm}$ $x\in\displaystyle \left(\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}E_\alpha\right)_{l_p}$,

(where for each $\alpha\in\Lambda$, $x_\alpha\in E_\alpha$).

Now, I think that the space$\displaystyle\left(\left(\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}E_\alpha\right)_{l_p}, \parallel.\parallel_p\right)$  is separable, but I could not see this statement/result in any reference (except some results saying that a countable $l_p$-direct sum of separable Banach spaces is separable).

Is there any reference/result in this direction? If not, and if the above claim is true, can someone provide a proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.

For each $\alpha \in \Lambda$  take a $x_\alpha\in E_\alpha$ such that $||x_\alpha||_{E_\alpha}=1$, then we have an uncountable collection of open balls in $\sum E_\alpha$, centered on the $x_\alpha$ (more precisely centered on the points of the form $x_\alpha$ in the coordinate $\alpha$ and $0$ in every other coordinate) that are all disjoint. Thus the space $\sum E_\alpha$ is not separable.

Comment: Even if the index set $\Lambda$ is a partially ordered and directed set?

Comment: I don't know what directed mean but this is really just about cardinality.

Comment: The $\ell_p$-sums over arbitrary index sets do not see any extra structure on them. So as long as the index set is uncountable and $E_\alpha$ are non-zero, the resulting space is non-separable because it contains an uncountable, discrete set of unit vectors.